# Python subprocess.run with shell=true ,verify input before being passed to subprocess

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, subprocess, containers

I have been using subprocess.run with shell=true and input as psql command to connect db instances from container .But now ,i want to restrict users from running destructive commands by prompting if there is any destructive commands like delete, select * from table_name and many more .In order to achieve i have to read what query is being passed to subprocess terminal which i don't know how to get via python .
Current way to connect `postgres` db

```
 subprocess.run(formateed_psql_command_with_user_name_host, shell=true, env=database_password)
```

I have tried to use `Popen` command but couldn't understand how to capture pipeline after subprocess has been running . I was expecting that input pipeline can be captured before being passed to psql connection subprocess and checked by string searching whether query contains destructive command or not

Comment: Can't you look inside the `formateed_psql_command_with_user_name_host` before `subprocess.run` ?

Comment: since these credentials are root user credentials created by terraform and stored in secret manager and thus have full access which we need to avoid .